# Selenium Ghost browser unexpected exited status 0

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ghost

Browser opens and driver loses its control. It starts the browser but it can't initiate the driver in order to use it and send_keys, or do anything.

The code runs using **Ghost Browser**, which is a *chromium* based browser.

What should be done in order to selenium get control over browser?

Ive tried to get session_id in order to attach selenium to existing browser but it didnt worked also, since it cant get the session_id, because selenium exits.

Code:

```
exe_path = r'C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\GhostBrowser\Application\ghost.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=exe_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=exe_path)

Are you sure you use chrome? Maybe change the webdriver.**Chrome**

Comment: The intention is to use other browser, but Chromium based, the docs says it is possible to open Chromium based browsers using Chrome webdriver.

Comment: After ChromeDriver team contact, they said it was made to work with Chrome only.